# nginx error " 504 Gateway Timeout"

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I run wordpress on nginx and when I post a comment for my post, I get the error message "504 Gateway Timeout" from nginx. Can anybody tell me how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

**Quickly you need to navigate on this links**

see the similar or duplicate stacks on following links

1. [Django site on Nginx+FastCGI goes
   (504 gateway timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466963/django-site-on-nginxfastcgi-goes-504-gateway-timeout)
2. [How do I prevent a Gateway Timeout
   with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx)
3. [Drupal + Nginx + Php-cgi : 502 Bad
   Gateway error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514576/drupal-nginx-php-cgi-502-bad-gateway-error)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using fastcgi:

This has been answered before in the following question:

[How do I prevent a Gateway Timeout with FastCGI on Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx)

In short; Check out the configuration option 'fastcgi_read_timeout'.

Comment: Increasing the timeout to 500s is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your `nginx` configuration file. To avoid `nginx` **default timeouts**, you can put this in your configuration file.

```
location / {
   proxy_read_timeout 600s; // Here it is: 600s = 10 min.
   // Rest for your configuration file. 
}
```

- For more information on this, go [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/fci/6.5.0?topic=tls-504-gateway-time-out-error)